# how to check a particular asp.net validation control is valid?

Tags: asp.net, validation, webforms, asp.net-2.0, asp.net-3.5

In a web form there are different asp.net validation controls. Is it possible to check a particular validation control is valid ? For example on leaving focus of textbox, first I will check requiredFieldValidatorUserName is valid ? If it is valid then I will check on server using ajax that this user name is not booked already.

**Edit:**

Explaination: I want to check validity (that input was valid) of a validation control on client side.

Please guide.

Comment: Why dont you do server side validation for both of your requirements , I am not sure , if you can do validation of a validation control.

Comment: If you want it to check before posting back you need to do that client side. For something like the required field validator you should be able to set EnableClientScript="true" and it should validate immediately after leaving the textbox.

Comment: @Mhuammad Awais, I mentioned I want to do ajax work :)

do you feel I should go to server /

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way would be to use a [`CustomValidator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.aspx) with client side code, as this will display all the error messages, block form submission and also ensure that the validation is repeated at the server side - remember, just because you have client-side validation available, doesn't mean the user's seen it: **Always validate your input at the server as well**.

Your `CustomValidator` would then be coded to call the Ajax methods, and would show the error messages correctly to the client:

```
<asp:Label ID="UserNameLabel" AssociatedControlID="UserName" runat="server">
  UserName *:</asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="UserNameRequired" runat="server" 
                            ControlToValidate="UserName" EnableClientScript="true"
                            ErrorMessage="You must supply a username!" />
<asp:CustomValidator ID="UserNameCustom" runat="server"
                     ControlToValidate="UserName" 
                     ClientValidationFunction="CheckExisting"
                     OnServerValidate="UserNameCustomValidate"
                     ErrorMessage="Username already taken" />
```

And your ClientValidationFunction should look something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function CheckExisting(source, arguments) {
    // Pass the arguments.Value to your AJAX call:
    if (ajaxCallUserNameTaken(arguments.Value)) {
      arguments.IsValid = false;
    }
  }
</script>
```

(Obviously, you'll need to write the ajaxCallUserNameTaken method to call your page method/web service/etc.)

Doing it this way will ensure that the validation methods happen as expected; this will get called whenever the user tabs out of the textbox **leaving a value** (it won't get called if the textbox is empty), and will ensure that the user can't submit the page until they supply a unique value. You'll also want to create the method referenced in `OnServerValidate` to ensure that the value's good once it hits the server too - this should call the same code that the AJAX endpoint uses to reduce duplication of code, etc.

I was originally going to suggest that you could use the `Page_Validators` object on the client-side to do some checking in the `onBlur` event, but I don't really think this is suitable here as it results in more pain:

1. It assumes that although there might be more than one validator on the page, there's only the RequiredFieldValidator on the control we're checking
2. The RequiredFieldValidator isn't fired during `OnBlur` if a user moves out of a control without setting a value - only if they set and clear the value, so even if `isvalid` is `true`, you need to check for an empty string!

Answer (score 6):

All validator controls implement IValidator which contains the IsValid property.

```
myValidatorControl.IsValid
```

Comment: Is it on client side ? I thing it is on server side.

Comment: No sorry, either I missed that req or it was a late add.

Answer (score 1):

I have just faced the same issue and I Set `CausesValidation="true"` to the textbox control and it worked. Just give it a try :)

Answer (score 1):

You could do this by setting the [ValidationGroup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227424.aspx) for the Validator control that you want to treat as separate from the others. Make sure it matches the ValidationGroup of the control it's validating (your username field).

Comment: I dont want to treat a control separate, rather I just want to check if input was valid ? then i will be dping ajax work on input.

Comment: Yes, but you seem to want to check it _separately_ to the others on the page, as opposed to all at once (via AJAX or otherwise)

Answer (score 0):

I have been messing around with this around for a bit and found a rather easy (not so efficient) solution to handle this using jQuery.

Use this function to check the validity of your control:

```
function validateControl() {
    return $('#YOUR_VALIDATOR_ID').css("visibility") == "visible"
```

if you're using `Display="Dynamic"` on your validator then the function is like so:

```
function validateControl() {
    return return $('#YOUR_VALIDATOR_ID').css("display") == "inline"
```

Be sure to check the true ID of your validator if you're using a Masterpage, as it will be different than the one in your IDE. Do so by viewing the page source in your browser.

The best solution will be of course to validate your form in some other way, using JavaScript or a CustomValidator that lets you write your own code.