# Trigger the status of the client side validation

Tags: asp.net, validation, requiredfieldvalidator

I have a .net form with several text Fields and some of them are marked with the RequiredFieldValidator.

```
<asp:TextBox MaxLength="150" Width="300" runat="server" ID="CityTXT"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ControlToValidate="CityTXT"
                                    ValidationGroup="PersoanlDetailsVG" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Enter City">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

I need to call a javascript function only if all these fields have values.

How could I trigger the status of the specific client side validation?

Thanks

**EDIT**

I tried to implement the Page_ClientValidate but the page doesn't postBack.

Here is my code

```
function Validate() {
        var res = Page_ClientValidate("PersoanlDetailsVG");

        if (res == true) {
            //do someting
        }
        return res;
    }

<asp:Button Visible="false"  CssClass="Proceedtopayment" runat="server"  OnClientClick="Validate();return false;" OnClick="ConfirmBooking" CausesValidation="true" ValidationGroup="PersoanlDetailsVG" />
```

It never executes the ConfirmBooking()

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to check a particular asp.net validation control is valid ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441347/how-to-check-a-particular-asp-net-validation-control-is-valid) - See my answer to the linked question - the RequiredFieldValidator will return IsValid in the first instance if there's never been a value in the field. A better option would be a `CustomValidator` as well as a RequiredFieldValidator.

Comment: @Zhaph - Ben Duguid thanks for you comment, but I don't need validation for a particular object. I need to trigger the status of the existing validation

Comment: @StrouMfios: I've [edited my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6573615/trigger-the-status-of-the-client-side-validation/6573706#6573706) according to your updates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [clientside validation API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479045.aspx#aspplusvalid_clientside) from ASP.NET.

You could check if `Page_IsValid` on clientside to detect if all validators are valid.

> A boolean variable that indicates
>   whether the page is currently valid.
>   The validation scripts keep this up to
>   date at all times.

For example:

```
if(Page_IsValid){
   foo();
}
```

The necessary `WebUIValidation.js`-file is automatically included if

- The page contains one or more validation Web controls.
- The page is being visited by an “uplevel” browser.

According to your updated answer: You page doesn't postback because you return `false` in all cases in `onClientClick`.

You must return the result of the validation if you want to postback on Button-Click if validation was successful:

```
OnClientClick="return Validate();"
```

The difference in @Brian's solution and mine is that `Page_ClientValidate()` is a function that triggers the validation(and internally returns `Page_IsValid`) while `Page_IsValid` only returns the state of the validation. Because the validation scripts keep `Page_IsValid` up to date at all times, it's redundant to call `Page_ClientValidate()`.

Comment: The use of Page_IsValid() method, performs a client side validation but it get called from server side. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: There is no method on serverside that performs a client-side validation because that would be a contradiction. The method you mean is a property of `Page` called [IsValid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.isvalid.aspx). This property should be called after [Page.Validate()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ke7bxeh.aspx) what triggers all validators on serverside. You should always check both, on server- and clientside. But return to the subject: i've provided a link in my answer where you can find all clientside validation variables and functions.

Comment: Thanks Tim Schmelter, great comment.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use custom validator in this case and make clientvalidation function and do your work if values provided

Answer (score 0):

When you include asp .net validators onto your aspx page then a series of validation scripts are automatically included on your client side rendered page. These scripts include a function called "Page_ClientValidate" which when called checks the validator state for those validators which support client side checking.

You can check the client side validation state using the following;

```
var validPage = Page_ClientValidate();
```

Comment: I implemented your suggestion but the page doesn't postBack. I edited my initial post